# What is the justification in ZFC for saying the class of all sets consists of pure sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The textbook on ZFC I am reading states about the class of all sets: "Finally, the sets in class $L$ are often referred to as pure sets." It goes on to define pure sets, but not before or after does it explain  why every set in the class $L$ should be pure.

I read that the pure sets are necessary to have finitely defined sets, and that [pure sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_set) are the intended interpretations of sets in ZFC, but I myself cannot figure out how to show this is true from the axioms or some implication of them.

The closest I can relate is the axiom of subsets, which states that any class definable by a property $P(set(x))$ is a subset - but this does not say *every element* of a set is also a set, as a pure set implies.

Book in question: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~randre/1aaset_theory_140613.pdf

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: Axioms and Set Theory - Robert Andre ; its free online

Comment: Great, then how about adding this information (and maybe a link) to your question, so people can more easily access it and answer your question?

Comment: The class, by the way, is $\scr S$, which is a script "S", rather than $L$.

Comment: The point is that a priori you might want to say that some mathematical objects are *not* sets. Perhaps the real numbers are somehow atomic entities, or at least the natural numbers? But ZFC is formulated in the language where every object is a set, so it makes sense to focus on pure sets, rather than sets which may or may not involve some other objects. And later you will see that indeed this is enough, and you can model the real numbers, and really any mathematical object, as pure sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not understanding; if every object in the language(?) of ZFC is a set, aren't all sets trivially pure?

Comment: The language of set theory is single-sorted, and objects are called "sets". So yes, trivially, every set is pure. But a priori, if you're not used to this kind of formality, for example if this is your very first course in set theory, you might not understand why the real numbers can be seen as sets, or the natural numbers, or a function.

Comment: Its making some more sense now. I have seen constructions of natural numbers by pairing incremental degrees of nested empty sets. I think I understand that sets are the fundamental object, and when I fully understand all the axioms, that they must be pure (let me know if that's an erroneous assumption). Classes are objects allowing for the collections based on properties of which naive set theory was based, which keeps sets safe from Russel's Paradox. I appreciate any corrections and the help so far.